# List Folder of Google Drive in android

Tags: android, file, directory, google-drive-api

I need to integrate Google drive in my android app.

i have integrated it successfully but by below code i can only get the file name , i want folder name also.

Here is my code :-

```
Files.List request = service.files().list();
textFiles = new HashMap<String, File>();
FileList files = null;
do {
     try {
        files = request.execute();

          for (File file : files.getItems()) {
                textFiles.put(file.getId(), file);
                Log.v("Test"+" :",file.getTitle());
                    i++;
        }

        Log.d("sdds", files + "");
        Log.d("first", files.size() + "");          
           request.setPageToken(files.getNextPageToken());
        } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
        request.setPageToken(null);
    }
   } while (request.getPageToken() != null && request.getPageToken().length() > 0);
```

Am i doing some thing wrong?

Thanks for Help.